# Anatomically Correct Pinocchio

Tags: creature-design, humanoid, shapeshifters

[Pinocchios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinocchio) are known to be mischievous creatures, but **why did they evolve that way and how do they survive?**

The creature has the following properties:

- Appears to be made of wood
- Not taller than a large dog sitting on its hind legs
- Has a nose that may vastly change in length
- Is of a humanoid shape

Additionally, some have said:

- Is born by being freed from a wood-like substance
- Is known to be in contact with 'blue fairies', whatever that may be
- May one day mature to become like a human boy
- May go through a phase of imitating young donkeys

Comment: I'm upvoting for the title, and how disappointed I was on reading the question :P I have no idea how to answer the question, though: a wood sprite? A Pokemon? A trickster god? A steampunk (woodpunk?) robot AI? A golem? Feels like there are far too many options, and that the question needs a setting to have a chance of an answer, but I'm not sure the lack is VTC-worthy.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry to hear of your dissappointment. What were you expecting or how could the question be improved?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking here.  You've already created this species (or, rather, you've outlined the criteria others have created for the singular character).  So that's the answer.  If a Pinocchio is anything other than what it is, that would just be changing the name.  Or perhaps coming up with a story idea (they're actually aliens!)  So what are you asking?

Comment: Agreed.. sounds to me like you are asking for a drawing? I am confused.

Comment: And just in case someone is not familiar with how the term "Anatomically Correct" is used in American English...it refers to a doll or drawing or something else, often for children, that has a correct depiction of genitals.  It can of course also be used more generally, without that reference, but, in America at least, it will often produce a snicker.

Comment: "Speaker for the Dead" (Orson Scott Card) comes to mind.  But, "the piggies" were opposite; they "turned to trees" when they died.

Comment: @ALambentEye: Nothing could be improved, and I was mostly joking about the disappointment. The title is humorously and misleadingly suggestive (a good thing, and why I upvoted), implying a more adult-content pinocchio, but in reality your question genuinely is asking about the *nose* growing! Again, this is not a problem at all, and does not need "improving" :) Such playfully-misleading titles have a rich tradition on SO, and are to be commended.

Comment: I think the question is fun,  but could be refined, like "where did pinocchio come from?  What society of pinocchios deposited him in that puppet shop? " or idk, that might be too opinion based,  but the question has to go somewhere.

Comment: @Cyn I've changed the focus of the question, is it better now?

Comment: @boxcartenant I've adjusted the question. Is this the sort of question you had in mind?

Comment: @Rob I mean... we could talk about This Guy... https://i0.wp.com/multiversitystatic.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/2018/12/maxresdefault-1.jpg?resize=1280%2C700

Comment: While it's a cute question, I'm gonna have to go with it's still pretty story based.  Though I haven't voted to close and it's getting answers.  So... I wood say it's probably oak-kay for now.

Comment: @ALambentEye Yeah, that's more like the kind of thing I'd expect to see on this site :) Good revision. Now I have to think about how to answer it....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Everybody knows how amazing the collective intelligence of the termites is!

While some of them like to carve their nests inside the wood, a particular race of termites has become particularly adapted to life inside dead pieces of wood.
This particular subfamily, the *Coptotermes Pinocchii* has adapted so well that it can move the log of wood, for defence or search of food.
When they colonize a piece of wood, they start to gather small sticks that attack to the wood thanks to a glue-like secretion, so that they seem limbs sprouting from the wood piece itself.
Then, the members of a particular group of soldier termite - that developed tha ability to stretch and elongate their bodies - start to attach, in the number of hundreds, to the joints of the limb-like appendages. Thanks to their adaptation and sheer number, they can develop enough strenght to move the piece of wood, as if it was a bipedal being! This way they can translate their nest toward new surces of food or far from predators.

Some termites, in order to better defend themselves from predators, can add on the middle part of the wood piece other arm-like appendages (usually two, even if nests with up to five "arms" have been observed), which are used to beat birds and ant-bears.
Similarly to some butterflies, whose wings look like eyes in order to confound predators, these termites use to secrete round patches of a white substance on the top of the nest. These fake eyes can scare birds and ant-bears and keep them far from the termites when they have to leave the nest in order to forage.

In order to better areate the tunnels that these termites carve inside the wood, they also use to extrude another appendage on the top of the wood piece (somehow similar to a nose), which is used to dissipate heath. This appendage, according to the temperature inside the nest, can be retracted or extended to better tune the heath dissipation.

Another peculiarity of the *Coptotermes Pinocchii* is the ability to release a toxic substance if they feel their nest is threatened. This substance is usually harmless to human beings, but it is known to give hallucinations if somebody breathes too much of it.
In particular, strange dream-like experiences, with visions of donkeys, children or bizarrely coloured humanoids, have been reported by woodcutters and woodcarvers who had ventured in the forests in search of wood and who happened to get too close to these nests.

Answer (score 5):

*Pinocchio Terribillis* is classified as a Euarchontoglires of unknown order, meaning while everyone is positive the species is a supraprimate is doesn't really fit in with other members of that clade -- primates, treeshrews, lagomorphs, and rodents.

Paleopinotologists have found fossilized remains of *Pinocchio Imnasis Nares*, a widely accepted ancestor of modern Pinocchio, everywhere *Homo Sapiens* and *Neanderthal* are also found.  This suggests a co-evolution of the species.

Of the many strange qualities they possess, the strangest is that species has always walked upright and moved with an odd jerky and swaying motion, almost as if they were held aloft by unseen strings.  This is thought to be a deceptive adaptation to confuse predators by making their motion unpredictable.

Their flesh is an inflexible fibrous material without interior bones and a thin exoskeleton similar to the excretions of the shellac beetle.  This exoskeleton overs their entire body except for their noses, which need to expand and contract, which is another amazing trait of these creatures.

It's not known why they evolved the ability to grow their noses by up to 1000% in length.  It has been suggested it was a primary characteristic in sexual selection, but since all three genders possess the trait that argument was the source of much controversy until the discovery of the **Pilton Pinocchio**.

That specimen, having been swallowed whole by a saber tooth tiger, its nose grew to such lengths it shattered the predator's ribs from the inside out.  Suggesting that the nose is similar to puff fish spines and the psychedelic ooze produced by some species of reptiles.

There are many folk tales about Pinocchio that are known to stem from ignorance and superstition.  They do not spring forth from wood.  They often seek shelter from predators within trees because their fibrous nature permits them to move through them as we do through water.  Stories of carving Pinocchio out of wood are misrepresentations of fact.  The Pinocchio was no doubt merely hiding when discovered.

They are also excellent mimics, surpassing Ravens and Parrots, and often imitate the play of species they observed to avoid attracting attention to themselves.  Herds of Pinocchio have been seen to be 'playing' at being donkeys or small boys.  As they mature, their mimic can become extremely sophisticated and permit them to pass as human children.  Again, this is thought to be an evolutionary adaptation to better avoid predators, since human communities are more successful at elimination external threats to their communities safety, than herds of Pinnochio are.

There is still a lot more to learn about this amazing species, and many learnings and current thinkings may not persist through the rigors of scientific inquiry.

Comment: I like how you made it into an in-universe answer.

Comment: @Writer-of-stories, I don't even remember answering this. It's good.  Must have had help.

Comment: Quick! Check if you are missing a kidney!

Comment: @Writer-of-stories,  very thoughtful of you to inquiry, but I’ve got all 8. I know it’s an odd number, but some people are so careless.